# Dynamically handling changes in IoT telemetry data payload in real-time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, amazon-kinesis

I'm working with a fleet of 300+ IoT devices sending telemetry data to a Kinesis Data Stream at a rate of 25 million messages per day. The data is stored in a MongoDB database using a schema with three collections:

- Devices
- Variables
- Values (timeseries)

**Problem:**

The devices can have their payload dynamically changed during operation, adding or removing variables. For example, a device named "machine-2" initially sends the following payload:

```
    {
      "currentPowerConsumption": 6.7,
      "upTime": 456789,
      "motorHealth": 100
    }
```

However, after a reconfiguration, it now sends:

```
    {
      "currentPowerConsumption": 6.7,
      "upTime": 456789,
      "motorHealth": 100,
      "motorTemperature": 45
    }
```

Current approach:

I'm currently using Redis to store the number of variables each device sends with a key-value pair like `device-id: number-of-variables`. For example:

```
"machine-2": 3
```

When a payload arrives, I:

1. Check the Redis store for the corresponding device ID.
2. If the number of variables hasn't changed, I directly insert the
   data into the **values** collection.
3. If the number of variables has changed, I update the **variables**
   collection and then insert the data into the **values** collection.

Questions:

1. Is this approach efficient and scalable for handling such a large
   volume of data?
2. Are there any potential improvements or alternative solutions I
   should consider for dynamically handling changes in the data
   payload?
3. Is storing the number of variables in Redis the best way to track
   schema changes, or are there other options?

Additional information:

1. The data is ingested from Kinesis Data Streams.
2. I'm using MongoDB as the backend database.
3. I need a robust and flexible solution to handle dynamic payload
   changes.